# why does this for loop iterating over 2d array not work

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, multidimensional-array, casting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{

    int a[4][5] =
    {
       {1,1,0,1,0},
       {0,0,0,0,0},
       {0,1,0,0,0},
       {1,0,1,1,0}
    };

    int *ptr = &a[0][0];

    for (; ptr < ptr+19; ptr++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *ptr);
    } 
  
    return 0;
    
}
```

Why does this code not work? as far as i know 2D arrays are stored in row major order so like this:

[1,1,0,1,0]-[0,0,0,0,0]-[0,1,0,0,0]-[1,0,1,1,0]

So if i started at &a[0][0] and incremented it by 1 each time until it has been incremented to the last element why does this not work?

Comment: `ptr` is always less than `ptr+19`, at least until the pointer runs off the end of the address space and wraps around, but it is likely to be pointing to invalid memory before that happens.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a useful statement.  What ***does*** it do?

Comment: Apart from the obvious bug `ptr < ptr+19` you aren't allowed to de-reference arrays in this manner. You go out of bounds in the array access and it's undefined behavior. The compiler is allowed to go nuts and generate strange code or a crashing program.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the danger caused from accessing data with pointers for different type, the loop condition is wrong.

`ptr+19` moves with `ptr` and the condition `ptr < ptr+19` will always be true (until overflow occurs).

Your code will be better if you retain the origin pointer and use that for stop condition.

```
    int *ptr = &a[0][0];
    int *start_ptr = ptr;

    for (; ptr < start_ptr+19; ptr++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *ptr);
    }
```

Comment: wait a minute the ptr+19 adds 19 to the pointer each time?!

Comment: @programmer29874 Yes... or maybe no because the condition `ptr < ptr+19` may be turned into an unconditional "true" by the optimizer.

Comment: wow i did not realize that Mike thanks a lot, you seem to be pro at C could you recommend me something to get better at C? maybe a book or some materials ;P

Comment: @programmer29874 Try it with `int`: `for (int x = 0; x < x + 19; x++) printf("%d ", x);`. How many iterations do you think it should do?

Comment: i will try that thanks, also guys what is this type of behavior called specifically what the way the pointer still gets incremented even when its being tested in a condition like in the for loop

Comment: @programmer29874 [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @programmer29874: this is not really a C issue. It's just that the mathematical expression `x < x + y`, where `0 < y` always holds true, regardless of if it's part of a program or just some manually executed arithmetic. The conditional part of a loop is evaluated *whole* on each iteration. The compiler is not a magical beast that sees an expression like `a < b` and *thinks* "oh, I'll have to reevaluate `b` and only `b` each time".

Comment: @programmer29874 You seem to be confused. `ptr`'s value does not get changed by `ptr < ptr+19`. `ptr` and `ptr+19` are two different pointer values, but the first is always less than the second (at least until it goes wrong).

Comment: but when the compiler sees ```ptr+19``` doesnt it add 19 to ptr then compare it to ```ptr```

Answer (score 0):

In this for loop

```
for (; ptr < ptr+19; ptr++)
```

the value of the expression `ptr` is always less than the value of the expression `ptr + 19` (provided that there is no overflow in the last expression). Moreover the pointer `ptr` is incremented after each iteration of the loop.

So using this loop you will get access to memory outside the array `a` that results in undefined behavior.

What you need is the following for statement

```
for ( ; ptr < ( int * )a + sizeof( a ) / sizeof( **a ); ptr++)
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[4][5] =
    {
       {1,1,0,1,0},
       {0,0,0,0,0},
       {0,1,0,0,0},
       {1,0,1,1,0}
    };

    for ( int *ptr = ( int * )a; ptr < ( int * )a + sizeof( a ) / sizeof( **a ); ptr++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *ptr );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: i have one question does the condition ```ptr < ptr+19``` add ```19``` to ```ptr``` each time its evaluated?

Comment: @programmer29874 ptr is incremented in the third expression of the for loop ptr++. In the second expression (condition) of the for loop there are compared two expressions ptr and ptr + 19.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

    int a[4][5] =
    {
       {1,1,0,1,0},
       {0,0,0,0,0},
       {0,1,0,0,0},
       {1,0,1,1,0}
    };

    int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0][0]) ;
    int * ptr = &a[0][0] ;
    while(len--)
    {
        printf("%d ", *ptr++);
    }
  
    return 0;
    
}
```